# Blazor WebAssembly Add headers to all API requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, blazor

I created a simple asp.net Web API that sends users from a SQL table.The API requires a key in the request header. I'm now creating a simple Blazor WebAssembly App that shows the users.
I am just adding a simple httpclient:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7280/")});
```

and then I create the typical crud operations. For example the request for all the users:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public UserService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }
    
    public async Task<List<UserDto>> GetUsers()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await this.httpClient.GetAsync("api/Users");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
                {
                    return Enumerable.Empty<UserDto>().ToList();
                }

                return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<UserDto>>(); 
            }
            else
            {
                var alert = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                throw new Exception($"Http status:{response.StatusCode} - {alert}");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to add header to all requests? Or do I have to make a custom request every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard pattern for adding behavior for all of your HTTP requests is to use [`DelegatingHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.delegatinghandler?view=net-6.0).  For your purposes, first create a class:

```
public class AddHeadersDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public AddHeadersDelegatingHandler() : base(new HttpClientHandler())
    {
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("X-MyTestHeader", "MyValue");  // Add whatever headers you want here

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Then just change your existing registration:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient 
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7280/")
});
```

To:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient(new AddHeadersDelegatingHandler()) 
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) 
});
```

The interesting points to note:

- **Do** provide a constructor to your `DelegatingHandler` and pass to the base constructor a new instance of `HttpClientHandler`.  If you miss this step you'll get a runtime error that the delegating handler hasn't been assigned a target.
- `SendAsync` **can** be an async method.  In this particular case, since it doesn't await anything, it's not.
- You could continue to use `new Uri("https://localhost:7280/")` but `builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress` is usually preferred.
- Naturally to do anything with the response, you should make the method async, await `base.SendAsync` (which provides you with the response), and do what you will with it.

Comment: I seem to have a problem with Cors. Before the APIKey, I solved this by putting the line: `app.UseCors(policy => policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7185", "https://localhost:7185").AllowAnyMethod().WithHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentType));` on my Web API's code. Do I have to allow Cors on the application too?

Comment: Actually never mind, I am an idiot. I obviously had to specify the WithHeaders to include the apikey in the UseCors. Thanks very much it worked perfectly!

Comment: @KostasSoulios great, glad it worked.  Was about to point you to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors) on that topic but looks like you're already on top of it. :)

Comment: What if  AddHeadersDelegatingHandler  had constructor parameters ? how can you register HttpClient?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76207158/blazor-registering-an-httpclient-and-passing-an-delegatinghandler-as-constructo