# RemoteAuthenticatorView throwing error when trying to sign in

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, keycloak, openid-connect

i created a new blazor WASM project with authentication (individual accounts) with VS 2022.
I'm using Keycloak as an identity provider with the authorization code grant flow.
The initial setup works just fine - i hit login and get redirected to the keycloak login screen, enter my username and password and got back to the blazor website. Then it says "There was an error trying to log you in: 'There was an error signing in.'"
When i add a method to the RemoteAuthenticatorView.LogInFailed event i can also hit a breakpoint there.
And that's what i don't understand. In wireshark i can see that the token endpoint returned 200 OK with access token and everything. I can even use that token in postman to call my api and it works.

I highly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Here is my blazor setup:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
  builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
  builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

  builder.RegisterHttpClient();

  builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
  {
    options.ProviderOptions.MetadataUrl = "http://localhost:8080/realms/Test/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "http://localhost:8080/realms/Test";
    options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "test-client";
    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";

    options.UserOptions.NameClaim = "preferred_username";
    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role";
    options.UserOptions.ScopeClaim = "scope";
  });

  await builder.Build().RunAsync();
  }

public static class Extensions
{
  public static void RegisterHttpClient(this WebAssemblyHostBuilder builder)
  {
    var httpClientName = "Default";

    builder.Services.AddHttpClient(httpClientName,
        client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
        .CreateClient(httpClientName));
  }
}
```

I also tried the same thing with the Duende Identity Provider (Online Demo) and that works without any problem. I checked what i got from that token endpoint and besides having not as much information and different values it has the same structure.

UPDATE: For anyone curious - i just missed the entry for the web origin in the keycloak client configuration and that caused a CORS error.
I'm new to this web stuff but i can imagine that this is something really basic.

Anyway thanks to @jdweng for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: Compare you working Postman results using sniffer with c# code.  Then make c# look exactly like working postman.  The default settings for a http connection is different in c# and Postman.  Usually it is HTTP header(s) that have to be modified.

Comment: @jdweng Unfortunately i don't know how to modify the headers when c#/blazor posts to the token endpoint. Would appreciate an idea on how to do it.

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72722026/blazor-webassembly-add-headers-to-all-api-requests?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, this led me to check the right things. I missed the weborigin entry in the keycloak client configuration which caused a CORS error.