# Blazor: Registering an HttpClient and passing an DelegatingHandler as constructor parameter which has dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to add custom HEADERS to all my outgoing requests.
I have created a DelegatingHandler like this:

```
public class AddGateHeaderDelegatingHandler:DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ICurrentCenterProvider currentCenterProvider;

    public AddGateHeaderDelegatingHandler(ICurrentCenterProvider currentCenterProvider) : base(new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        this.currentCenterProvider = currentCenterProvider;
    }
    
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var gateName = await currentCenterProvider.GetCurrentGateName();
        request.Headers.Add("GateName", gateName);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I want to send current gate name in all outgoing http requests.

everything is good so far but when I want to register my HttpClient I can't pass ICurrentCenterProvider to my AddGateHeaderDelegatingHandler constructor because I have no access to it. look at this :

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(builder =>
{
    var httpClient=new HttpClient(new AddGateHeaderDelegatingHandler(what should I pass here?));
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(gatewayUrl);
    return httpClient;
});
```

As you can see I need to instantiate my AddGateHeaderDelegatingHandler class but it has a constructor parameter that I need to pass when instantiating.

How can I pass an instance of ICurrentCenterProvider  to AddGateHeaderDelegatingHandler  when registering my HttpClient?

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(x => x.BaseAddress = "BASE_ADDRESS").AddHttpMessageHandler<AddGateHeaderDelegatingHandler>();
```